# Drag and Drop Richfaces

Tags: java, google-chrome, mozilla

I have an idea to work on a sample solution (**web app** or **java desktop app**) to drag and drop **richfaces** components.
I know there are some plugins out there for(eclipse, netbeans ..) that can get the job done, but i'm trying to make something custom.

does anyone have an idea how should i proceed ? a hint to help me start will be enought ..

[image: richfaces logo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with this: [Richfaces Showcase Drag and Drop](http://showcase.richfaces.org:8000/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dragDrop&skin=blueSky).
You can have a look at the source and maybe get an Idea where to start.